# How to answer a rejection e-mail from the company you've worked for before?

Tags: rejection

I worked for one company for some time and quit the job myself due to some personal reasons. I decided to re-apply for the same position as my situation has changed. I was interview by the company 2 times (On the phone with HR and then in the office with managers) but still received an e-mail stating they are not ready to take me back in the team (The position is now relocated in another office, lots of things that might have influenced their decision, I don't even know).

The question now is: how should I answer their rejection e-mail without looking pitiful?

Answer (score 14):

> The question now is: how should I answer their rejection e-mail
>   without looking pitiful?

There's no need to answer a rejection email. That email is the conclusion of the interview process.

If you feel that you must, a simple "Thank you for your consideration." would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by Joe Strazzere, a rejection email is the conclusion of the hiring process, and no email answer will change the outcome.

If you absolutely want to work for that company, and are willing to accept another job, you could write something like the following:

> Dear Sir or Madam,
>
> I understand that the job I have applied for is not available anymore. However, I had a great experience with your company and I would love to come back. Are there any other open jobs at CompanyX for which I would be qualified ?
>
> I thank you for your understanding and your help (and so on)

However, if they rejected you without proposing anything, it might be that they are not interested in recruiting you at all, harsh as it may sound, and no email will change that either.